# How to read special character like "&" in WordPress post URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to load a single post with custom URL. But it is redirecting to default URL because of "&" character. without & character, it is working fine. But how can I read this "&" in URL? My code is below,

```
function mutually_add_query_vars($vars) {
    return array('L') + $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'mutually_add_query_vars');
```

and Loading for a single template

```
function mutually_template4($template) {

  global $wp;

  if ($wp->query_vars['L']=='6'.html_entity_decode('&').'au=2') {
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-ad.php';
  }
  else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter('single_template', 'mutually_template4');
```

I tried with html_entity_decode, but it works nothing.

Comment: my post URL will be like,L=2&utm_source=tb2&utm_campaign=mutually&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=tree&utm_term=MSN, but i have given sample

Comment: Sorry deleted comment as was a touch off the mark have you got an example where the value of L includes an &?

Comment: Brian, i am not getting you, the post i working as a sample post, http://localhost/wordpress/2018/06/rescued-circus-tiger-takes-cautious-first-step-into-his-new-home/?L=6&au=2, but it is not working, it redirecting to default layout

Comment: Ohh yep so those are 2 separate params i was right in my initial comment *doh* try changing the conditional to `if ($wp->query_vars['L']=='6' &&  $wp->query_vars['au']=='2')`

Comment: sorry, brother, it is not working

Comment: I'd suggest outputting the values of $wp->query_vars['L'] and $wp->query_vars['au'] just to make sure we're testing them right. If branching templates like this I usually just test the vars within the template then either use template parts or just inline the differences if they're quite similar. But yeah 2 likely causes of failure I see - 1. the test isn't working and is returning default template. 2. the template reassignment isn't working

Comment: it is working with /?L=6abcde slug but not having with &, do you have any suggest?

Comment: Perhaps `print_r($wp->query_vars)` on one of the failing urls might shed a little light

Comment: how, will i print_r() it?

Comment: Within whichever template that's rendering when it's failing assuming isn't throwing an errror

Comment: no, when it is not getting $wp->query_vars['L']=='6'.html_entity_decode('&').'au=2' it is returning else return $template;

Comment: it is not reading the & character

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that the & shouldn't be included as a key or value for the examples you've provided.

Comment: brother, for ad service providing i have to do this, this way

Comment: when, i am using $wp->query_vars['L']=='6%26au=2', with print_r it is returning Array ( [L] => 6&au=2 [page] => [year] => 2018 [monthnum] => 06 [name] => rescued-circus-tiger-takes-cautious-first-step-into-his-new-home ), here it is printing "&"

Comment: Alrighty in that case   `if ($wp->query_vars['L']=='6%26au=2')` should do the trick but think the reasoning behind needing all the URI encoding seems to be that perhaps `mutually_add_query_vars` is doing something a little off and joining the values may- it's worth noting the above solution will only work if the L and au params are in order & and = are reserved characters so within a GET value need to be URI encoded but in this case = doesn't appear to be encoded for some reason

Comment: ?L=6%26au=2 converting in print_r Array ( [L] => 6&au=2) but in post url ?L=6&au=2 not getting the current page

Comment: Brian, have you any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you mean the if i provided should eval as truthy so if the template path is correct I'd expext it to work as intended assuming query params are provided in order - if not then need to look at `mutually_add_query_vars` and fix how it's adding the params then use the `if` in my answer. Ive got to sleep soon sorry so may go silent shortly

Answer (score 0):

You need to **encode**
So & will be %26

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is URL encoding instead of HTML encoding (Both are different). Therefore, you can replace & with %26. [Click here](https://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/url_encode.html) to see reference to URL encoding.

You can also use urlencode ( string $str ) PHP function to encode a string with URL friendly values.

Comment: brother urlencode is not working, i tried with this, $wp->query_vars['L']=='6'.urlencode('%26').'au=2'

Answer (score 0):

GET parameter pairs in a URL start with a ? then are separated by an & symbol and key/values are separated by an = so myurl.com?L=6&au=2 would be parsed into two separate `$wp_query_vars` elements one being assigned to `L` and the other to `au` there should be no need to manually parse out the & symbol if for some reason your key/value included an & it would need to be URI encoded as %26 as other answers have suggested :)

```
function mutually_template4($template) {

  global $wp;

  if ($wp->query_vars['L']=='6' && $wp->query_vars['au']=='2') {
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-ad.php';
  }
  else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter('single_template', 'mutually_template4');
```